# Xcode - same team names

Tags: xcode

The company I work for has 2 apple developer accounts. one is an account for **Standard Company**, another one is for **Enterprise**. Both accounts has same company name.

In Xcode 6.4, we can choose a team in the `General` tab of `Targets` setting.
And the problem is that I can't recognize which team is for Enterprise.

[image]

There are 2 teams, but those are all same name. So it's really confusing for me to choose an appropriate team. Moreover, it seems that an order of the teams is sometimes changed.

What would you do if you are in my situation?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd hope to choose the right one...

Comment: Did you find a way out of this?

Comment: @JeanLeMoignan No I couldn't find it yet.

Comment: I finally fell back to the simplest solution to get that project shipped: I removed myself from "wrong team", then had only "real team" to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is given by the apple in the Xcode 8.0. It is showing Enterprise/Company after the team name with brackets. so you can clearly identify it now :)